# No puedo linkear mi archivo Css a mi html en mi proyecto Java

Tags: java, html, css

Les dejo mi fragmento de codigo de lo que estoy queriendo hacer.

Mi css y el Html ya los eh probado en Visual Studio Code y funcionan perfecto. Es un simple Menú que estoy queriendo utilizarlo como layout, pero para probarlo lo estoy usando en cada vista, además que todavia nosé cómo hacer un Layout en Eclipse.

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

*, *::before, *::after{
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

body{
    line-height: 1.6;
}

header{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

ul{
    text-align: center;
}

nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    min-height: 8vh;
    background-color: rgb(50, 56, 66);
}

.enlaces-menu{
    display: flex;
}

.enlaces-menu li{
    padding: 0 40px;
    list-style-type: none;
    color: #fff;
    transition: 0.3s;
    margin: 10px;
}

.enlaces-menu li a{
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.enlaces-menu li:hover{
    background-color: rgb(62, 130, 197);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btnCerrarSesion{
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 600;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
    <header>
          <div>
            <nav>
              <ul class="enlaces-menu">
                <li type="button"><a href="#">Biblioteca</a></li>
                <li type="button"><a href="#" >Prestamos</a></li>
                <li type="button"><a href="#">Clientes</a></li>     
              </ul>
              <ul class="enlaces-menu">
                <li>
                  <button class="btnCerrarSesion">Cerrar Sesión</button>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
    </header>
```

Y asi se ve

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy tratando de linkear mi css a mi html en Java. Estoy usando el IDE Eclipse.

Acá tengo mi archivo Css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y así es como estoy linkeando:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/Main.css"/>
```

o `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/Main.css"/>`
Y me dice que no existe la etiqueta `Header`, lo que me resulta raro.

Comment: No estoy seguro de como funciona ese un IDE (nunca lo he usado para desarrollo web) pero, si mal no recuerdo, al poner los dos puntos (`../`) estas llamando a la carpeta raiz, en tu caso, llamas a `Web Content` y dentro de esta, no existe la carpeta css. Es posible que por eso no te este llamando a los estilos de tu hoja.

Comment: Gracias! voy a ver eso...

Comment: Parece que ni con la virgurilla o los dos puntos no me funciona...

Answer (score 0):

Yo probaría con `href="/WEB-INF/lib/css/Main.css"`, en este caso la ruta es absoluta desde la raíz del proyecto y debería funcionar.

Comment: Tampoco me funcionó..